# What is VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL and fnStringSplit?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

This is taken from a stored procedure. I'm not sure what the code in the second half of the where statement is doing. How is `@DivisionList` being used when there is no value to it? What is `fnStringSplit`? Any help would be great. Thanks

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
              
    ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAppGetSAMDataForBARCValidationAudit]
@DivisionList VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@RegionList VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@PlanIDList VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@LastUpdateByID CHAR(7),
@SyncType CHAR(15) = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
    IF (@SyncType = 'BARCtoMAAUI')
    BEGIN                       
        IF (SELECT  OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmpTPFMRA2')) IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #tmpTPFMRA2;
        END;
        SELECT DISTINCT
               PlanYearID,
               CPS AS BidYearCPBPS,
               LastUpdateDateTime AS [date]
        INTO #tmpTPFMRA2
        FROM [dbo].[Trend_SavedPopulationBarcBidYearMembership] WITH (NOLOCK);

        IF (SELECT  OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#tmpTPFMarketAdj2')) IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #tmpTPFMarketAdj2;
        END;
        SELECT DISTINCT
               CPS AS BidYearCPBPS,
               LastUpdateDateTime AS [date]
        INTO #tmpTPFMarketAdj2
        FROM [dbo].[Trend_SavedPopulationMarketAdjustment] WITH (NOLOCK);             

        --GET bidyear value 
        DECLARE @BidYear2 INT;
        SELECT @BidYear2 = dbo.fnGetBidYear();

        SELECT DISTINCT
               pl.PlanYear,
               pl.CPS,
               pl.LastCPS,
               ISNULL(pl.PlanInfoID, 0) PlanInfoID,
               pl.Division,
               pl.Region,
               pl.Product,
               pl.SNPType,
               pl.PlanType,
               ISNULL(pl.IsHidden, 0) IsHidden,
               ISNULL(cw.BidYear, 0) CWBidYear,
               cw.SSStateCountyCD,
               cw.BaseYearCPS,
               cw.CurrentYearCPS,
               cw.BidYearCPS,
               ISNULL(cw.ServiceAreaOptionID, 0) ServiceAreaOptionID,
               cw.ServiceAreaOptionName,
               cw.ServiceAreaOptionDescription,
               ISNULL(cw.BidYearRenewalTypeID, 0) BidYearRenewalTypeID,
               ISNULL(cw.BidYearPlanInfoID, 0) BidYearPlanInfoID,
               ISNULL(cw.CurrentYearPlanInfoID, 0) CurrentYearPlanInfoID,
               ISNULL(cw.IsActive, 0) IsActive,
               ISNULL(tpfMRA.[date], 0) AS MRALastUpdatedTime,
               ISNULL(tpfMarketAdj.[date], 0) AS MarketAdjLastUpdatedTime,                    
               @BidYear2 AS BidYear
       
        FROM vwPlanInfo pl WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                       BidYear,
                       SSStateCountyCD,
                       BaseYearCPS,
                       CurrentYearCPS,
                       BidYearCPS,
                       ServiceAreaOptionID,
                       ServiceAreaOptionName,
                       ServiceAreaOptionDescription,
                       BidYearRenewalTypeID,
                       BidYearPlanInfoID,
                       CurrentYearPlanInfoID,
                       IsActive
                FROM vwSAMCrosswalks WITH (NOLOCK)
            ) cw
                ON pl.PlanInfoID = cw.BidYearPlanInfoID
                   AND pl.PlanYear = cw.BidYear                 
            LEFT JOIN #tmpTPFMRA2 tpfMRA WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON pl.PlanYear = tpfMRA.PlanYearID
                   AND pl.CPS = tpfMRA.BidYearCPBPS
            LEFT JOIN #tmpTPFMarketAdj2 tpfMarketAdj WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON pl.CPS = tpfMarketAdj.BidYearCPBPS                
        WHERE pl.PlanYear >
        (
            SELECT MIN(PlanYear) - 3
            FROM LkpPlanYear WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE IsProjectedYear = 1
        )
              AND
              (
                  (@DivisionList IS NULL)
                  OR pl.Division IN
                     (
                         SELECT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@DivisionList, ',')
                     )
              )
              AND
              (
                  (@RegionList IS NULL)
                  OR pl.Region IN
                     (
                         SELECT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@RegionList, ',')
                     )
              )
              AND
              (
                  (@PlanIDList IS NULL)
                  OR pl.PlanInfoID IN
                     (
                         SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@PlanIDList, ',')
                     )
              );             
    END;

   ELSE
    BEGIN

        SELECT DISTINCT
               PlanYearID,
               CPS AS BidYearCPBPS,
               LastUpdateDateTime AS [date]
        INTO #tmpTPFMRA
        FROM [dbo].[Trend_SavedPopulationBarcBidYearMembership] WITH (NOLOCK);

        SELECT DISTINCT
               CPS AS BidYearCPBPS,
               LastUpdateDateTime AS [date]
        INTO #tmpTPFMarketAdj
        FROM [dbo].[Trend_SavedPopulationMarketAdjustment] WITH (NOLOCK);

        SELECT DISTINCT
               cs.PlanInfoID,
               cs.ServiceAreaOptionID,
               cs.BasePlanInfoID,
               cs.Status,
               cs.RemovedMM,
               cs.MovingMM,
               cs.TotalMM,
               cs.SignificancePct,
               cs.IsWks1BasePlan
        INTO #tmpCalcSign
        FROM dbo.CalcSignificance cs WITH (NOLOCK);

        --GET bidyear value 
        DECLARE @BidYear INT;
        SELECT @BidYear = dbo.fnGetBidYear();

        SELECT DISTINCT
               pl.PlanYear,
               pl.CPS,
               pl.LastCPS,
               pl.PlanInfoID,
               pl.Division,
               pl.Region,
               pl.Product,
               pl.SNPType,
               pl.PlanType,
               ISNULL(pl.IsHidden, 0) IsHidden,
               ISNULL(cw.BidYear, 0) CWBidYear,
               cw.SSStateCountyCD,
               cw.BaseYearCPS,
               cw.CurrentYearCPS,
               cw.BidYearCPS,
               ISNULL(cw.ServiceAreaOptionID, 0) ServiceAreaOptionID,
               cw.ServiceAreaOptionName,
               cw.ServiceAreaOptionDescription,
               ISNULL(cw.BidYearRenewalTypeID, 0) BidYearRenewalTypeID,
               ISNULL(cw.BidYearPlanInfoID, 0) BidYearPlanInfoID,
               ISNULL(cw.CurrentYearPlanInfoID, 0) CurrentYearPlanInfoID,
               ISNULL(cw.IsActive, 0) IsActive,
               ISNULL(rfi.PlanInfoID, 0) RollupPlanInfoID,
               rfi.ServiceAreaOptionID RollupSAOptionID,
               rfi.RollupName,
               ISNULL(tpfMRA.[date], 0) AS MRALastUpdatedTime,
               ISNULL(tpfMarketAdj.[date], 0) AS MarketAdjLastUpdatedTime,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.PlanInfoID, 0) CalcPlanInfoID,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.ServiceAreaOptionID, 0) CalcServiceAreaOptionID,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.BasePlanInfoID, 0) CalcBasePlanInfoID,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.Status, '') [Status],
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.RemovedMM, 0.0) RemovedMM,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.TotalMM, 0.0) TotalMM,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.MovingMM, 0.0) MovingMM,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.SignificancePct, 0.0) SignificancePct,
               ISNULL(tmpCalcSign.IsWks1BasePlan, 0) IsWks1BasePlan,
               @BidYear AS BidYear

        --tmpCalcSign.Status,tmpCalcSign.RemovedMM,tmpCalcSign.TotalMM,tmpCalcSign.SignificancePct,tmpCalcSign.IsWks1BasePlan
        FROM vwPlanInfo pl WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                       BidYear,
                       SSStateCountyCD,
                       BaseYearCPS,
                       CurrentYearCPS,
                       BidYearCPS,
                       ServiceAreaOptionID,
                       ServiceAreaOptionName,
                       ServiceAreaOptionDescription,
                       BidYearRenewalTypeID,
                       BidYearPlanInfoID,
                       CurrentYearPlanInfoID,
                       IsActive
                FROM vwSAMCrosswalks WITH (NOLOCK)
            ) cw
                ON pl.PlanInfoID = cw.BidYearPlanInfoID
                   AND pl.PlanYear = cw.BidYear
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                       PlanInfoID,
                       ServiceAreaOptionID,
                       RollupName
                FROM vwRollupForecastInfo WITH (NOLOCK)
            ) rfi
                ON pl.PlanInfoID = rfi.PlanInfoID
            LEFT JOIN #tmpTPFMRA tpfMRA WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON pl.PlanYear = tpfMRA.PlanYearID
                   AND pl.CPS = tpfMRA.BidYearCPBPS
            LEFT JOIN #tmpTPFMarketAdj tpfMarketAdj WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON pl.CPS = tpfMarketAdj.BidYearCPBPS
            LEFT JOIN #tmpCalcSign tmpCalcSign WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON pl.PlanInfoID = tmpCalcSign.PlanInfoID
        WHERE pl.PlanYear >
        (
            SELECT MIN(PlanYear) - 3
            FROM LkpPlanYear WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE IsProjectedYear = 1
        )
              AND
              (
                  (@DivisionList IS NULL)
                  OR pl.Division IN
                     (
                         SELECT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@DivisionList, ',')
                     )
              )
              AND
              (
                  (@RegionList IS NULL)
                  OR pl.Region IN
                     (
                         SELECT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@RegionList, ',')
                     )
              )
              AND
              (
                  (@PlanIDList IS NULL)
                  OR pl.PlanInfoID IN
                     (
                         SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@PlanIDList, ',')
                     )
              );

    END;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorException NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @errSrc VARCHAR(MAX) = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 'SQL'),
            @currentdate DATETIME = GETDATE();

    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
           @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
           @ErrorException
               = N'Line Number :' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR) + N' .Error Severity :'
                 + CAST(@ErrorSeverity AS VARCHAR) + N' .Error State :' + CAST(@ErrorState AS VARCHAR);
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    ---Insert into app log for logging error------------------  
    EXEC spAppAddLogEntry @currentdate,
                          '',
                          'ERROR',
                          @errSrc,
                          @ErrorMessage,
                          @ErrorException,
                          @LastUpdateByID;
    ;

        END CATCH;
    END;
```

Comment: `fnStringSplit` is something defined on your SQL Server so only you know for sure. Going by name and usage I guess it is a custom table valued UDF. When I google it I get this https://github.com/zgudino/mssql-toolkit/blob/master/FNStringSplit.sql This is a function that takes a delimited string and splits it into rows. Later versions of SQL Server have this built in

Comment: _How is @DivisionList being used when there is no value to it?_ Correct. In your posted code it never has a value. There must be more code. What you've posted is only a code fragment. Going by the code it looks like it's meant to be a SP parameter. All these things are conjecture - post the full code

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I added the full code. Thanks for your help. I still don't think it's being used anywhere though I could be missing something. You're right on the fnStringSplit. Very helpful!!

Comment: You really shouldn't splatter `NOLOCK` all over the place, it's dangerous and can return completely incorrect results. It's not a "go faster" switch

Answer (score 0):

These variables represent comma-separated lists (a somewhat rudimentary way of passing a list into a query), then the query is filtering only if there is actually anything in the list:

```sql
              (
                  (@DivisionList IS NULL)  -- either the list is empty
                  OR pl.Division IN
                     (
                         SELECT Value FROM dbo.fnStringSplit(@DivisionList, ',')
                         -- this seems to be a table function which splits the string by commas
                         -- the result of the function is like another view or table
                     )
              )
```

So either the list is empty, or there is a match in the list.

Without the source for `fnStringSplit` I can't say further, but it's likely that its performance isn't good. In newer versions of SQL Server you can use `STRING_SPLIT` instead, which should perform better.

---

A better option is to pass in an actual Table-Valued Parameter, this is essentially a read-only table variable.

Then the code would be as follows:

```sql
              (
                  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @DivisionList)  -- either the list is empty
                  OR pl.Division IN
                     (
                         SELECT Value FROM @DivisionList
                         -- no need to split
                     )
              )
```

Comment: Hey Charlie, appreciate the response and help. From the SP I posted, how do I know what's in this list when the only time they reference it is in the beginning of the code where they are defining the variables?

Comment: It's a parameter, it's passed in by whoever calls the stored procedure